# NSDateFormatter fails with NSInvalidValue on tester device, but not on mine

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have issues with date parsing. It works on my devices and simulator, but not on client device (which is also iPhone iOS 5.1.1, but maybe a different configuration)

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate          *date = nil;
    NSError         *error = nil; 

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM y HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    if (![formatter getObjectValue:&date forString:@"Mon, 21 Jun 2012 21:21:21 GMT" range:nil error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
```

which outputs

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)" UserInfo=0x446f10 {NSInvalidValue=Mon, 21 Jun 2012 21:21:21 GMT}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the locale on the date formatter to `en_US_POSIX`.

```
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

Comment: Great thanks ! Any idea why it would work on the simulator and devices, but not the tester device ? I even tried multiple languages

Comment: It depends on the locale. iOS will change your format string to add AM/PM rather than use 24h clock if the user has that set in their settings. This is not the case for the `en_US_POSIX` locale.

Comment: Thank you so much. This saved hours of frustration on a crazy bug that only affected the client in the UK and not the developers in North America.